# LinkedIn URL scheme to open company profile in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, linkedin-api, url-scheme

I have tried the below code for open LinkedIn company profile in the native LinkedIn iPad app. It doesn't work.

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://company?id=companyCode"]];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this scheme:

```
"linkedin://company/companyCode"
```

So your code will be something like that:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"linkedin://company/companyCode"]];
```

Comment: @Alessio Cancian Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
linkedin://profile/company/[companyid]
```

It works for me

Comment: Possibly backward-compatible? Checkout my answer; seems like newer APIs are in place.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays as per https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages Get a company's profile section, the API is [GET] https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}?format=json